# How to add custom fields using conditions in ingest pipeline (Elastic stack)?

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

Need to add a new field called app_statuscode for in filebeat. The condition is that if message field contains 404 or 502 the value of app_statuscode must be set to failed.
If the Message field contains 200 OK then the value must be set to successful.
Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can make use of several processors in ingest node pipelines to achieve this. It depends on the log formats if it's JSON then use json processor as it breaks json message into json objects. Once this is done we can access every values using dot operator.

1. Use json processor and mention target field name as messageinfo
2. Use set processor and mention condition ctx.messageinfo.status==200 then add a new field called status_code with success.

Grok patterns are another alternative to fix this issue. If the message is in string format use a grok pattern and then set operator to insert status value.